# In Java how do you Title Case a String while preserving some common abbreviations

Tags: java, title-case

There are many ways to [Title Case in java](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Convert_a_string_to_proper_case).

But how do you prevent some of the common abbreviations from being converted.  For Example;

```
System.out.println(makeProper("JAMES A SWEET");
System.out.println(makeProper("123 MAIN ST SW");

James A Sweet
123 Main St Sw
```

SW should remain uppercase as it is an abbreviation to South West.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some sort of dictionary that contains words that should not be capitalized. You could use a `HashSet` for that. Something along these lines:

```
Set<String> whiteList = new HashSet<String>();
whiteList.add("SW");
whiteList.add("NW");
// ...
for (String word : phrase.split()) {
    if (!whiteList.contains(word)) {
        makeProper(word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way to do such a thing.

You could come up with your own method and a set of abbreviations you don't want "corrected" and exclude does from the transformation

Comment: i agree.  seems to be a roll your own situation.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i could see is:

```
1. split your input text into words  
2. iterate through words  
      2.a  if word is a abbreviation then 
           2.a.1   do nothing or convert to uppercase, whatever is required  
    2.b  otherwise  
           2.b.1   call [makeProper][1] or [capitalize][2]
```

[makeProper](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Convert_a_string_to_proper_case#Java) or [capitalize](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully%28java.lang.String%29)
*obviously you have to create a method which will decide if the word is an abbreviation or not* :) how about keeping all know abbreviation in a file, and reading them.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#line.239) contains WordUtils.capitalizeFully which I've used to capitalise strings without problem. Hope it saves you time.